# for loop for 0 to n number with digits specification

Tags: javascript, html

How can I write a for loop for 16 digit number from 0 to `n`

I want the output to be like:

```
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000002
0000000000000003
0000000000000004
0000000000000005
```

Tried this but this isn't working:

```
for(i = 0000000000000000; i < 0000000000000010; i++){
    $("#TestDiv").append(i);
}
```

check out the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/co5t9kcu/)

Comment: Preceding `0`'s are not preserved in Numbers. Use String instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function writeNumber(n){
            var nLen = n.toString().length;
            var zeroLen = 16-nLen;
            var arr = [];
            var str = "0";
            for(var z=0;z<zeroLen;z++){
                arr.push(str);
            }
            arr.push(n.toString());
            return arr.join('');
        }

    window.onload = function () {


        var arr = [];
        for(i=0;i<11;i++){
            var str = writeNumber(i);
            arr.push(str);
        }

        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = arr.join('<br>');

    };

    </script>

    <div id="testDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

More efficient with an array. Maybe it doesn't matter so much when the loop is just 10 items, but you're going to write to the DOM 10 times if you access the DOM inside the loop instead of outside the loop just 1 time. All the 
small things adds up, so it may matter.

[9. Stop touching the DOM, damnit!](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using the `slice` method. For example:

```
var addLeadingZeros = function(number){
    var str = "0000000000" + number; // add leading zeros for single digit number
    return str.slice(-10); // slice the whole number down from the end
}
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    $("#TestDiv").append(addLeadingZeros(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because for number `00000001` is equal to `1` . You've to use strings.

Use like bellow

```
var str = '';
var zeros = '0000000000000000'; //string of 16 0's
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
    var temp = zeros.slice(i.toString().length); // get the 0's 16-length of i
    str += temp+i+'<br>';
}

$("#TestDiv").append(str);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/co5t9kcu/2/)

Comment: @JoseMagana It's kind of obvious that the number will go over 10 in the real situation... look at the leading 0s.

Comment: @Mritunjay - What I would normally do is something like `('0000000000000000'+10).slice(-16)` but yours also work.